# What is Redstone used for in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've found several piles of Redstone in [Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net), but I can't seem to find a coherent explanation as to what it does or how to use it.

Does anyone know what it's used for, and how to use it correctly and strategically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Redstone](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_%28ore%29) can be mined with Iron or better Picks to produce [Redstone Dust](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_%28dust%29).

Redstone Dust has a number of uses:

- Traps (land-mines and similar)
- Door (automation)
- Minecarting (junctions)
- Complicated gate systems
- Miscellenaous Mechanisms

Because it can be used to create [Electrical wires](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_circuits) and even [circuits](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_circuits#Logic_Gates).

Comment: Land mines? Is this in the current alpha or a mod? :S

Comment: @Tyro TNT + Wire + Pressure Plate

Comment: Or you can just put a pressure plate on top of TNT for those of you who don't have a pile of red stone to waste

Comment: @alex that works too, but its largely off topic.

Comment: I'm just here to spread the explosive joy.

Comment: Just to add to the answer; Redstone is also used in brewing, modifying certain potions to extend their effect duration. It can also be made into Redstone Blocks in a crafting table (fill the crafting table with Redstone), for aesthetic purposes where red wool is not practical.

Comment: People have even created whole memory banks, using redstone "piston logic gates". Its a computer within a computer! :O

Comment: and as of recent, people have made more computers within those computer-computers. redstone is more complicated than even IBM's Watson, if you think about it enough.

Answer (score 16):

[Redstone](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone), as it is officially named, is primarily used for the construction of various electrical circuits and mechanisms in Minecraft. By producing Redstone Torches and Wires, you can create a variety of mechanical traps and automatic mechanisms to further improve your mines.

It can also be used to produce gadgets such as the [Compass](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Compass), which is extremely useful.

Answer (score 10):

Redstone pretty much opens up an enormous world of possibilities in Minecraft. Once you discover those possibilities the game becomes incredibly more complex than it was before you played with redstone.

If you look up "Minecraft 16-bit ALU" and watch the video you find, you will see what I mean.

I've spent the last week or so learning about logic gates, and I use minecraft to test my builds. So far I've got a really compact 8-bit ripple carry adder built, but getting it all wired up  and connected to other components has been difficult.

You can do all kinds of things with redstone. You can make clocks, traps, automated doors, ignite tnt from a safe distance, use redstone and pressure plates to announce the location of a subject in a maze... the list goes on and on and on. Redstone by itself is amazing, but combined with everything else in the game it exponentially increases your opportunities for creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Red stone is an ore that can be mined with an iron pick.
It is used for making redstone curcuits like traps,XOR gates and even just opening doors.
you can place it on blocks to make a wire leading to a switch or button. You can also use redstone to make compasses or clocks.

Answer (score -2):

Redstone is a ore that can be mined with a iron or more advanced pick axe and is used to make clocks , compasses , and powered rail ect.

Comment: That is a good response, but I know there is a lot more parts to it. Go grab a source and add more info and will be a more valid answer.

Comment: Maybe it would have been kind of OK were it the first response, but a single sentence response that adds nothing to a 3.5 year old question? This is not something to be encouraged.